# Selecting int values using a cursor query

Tags: android, sql, cursor

I am new to Android, and having some basic problems. One of them is the use of queries.
I store a boolean value as either 1 or 0 in the table (INTEGER field). However, when I select either on 1 or 0 using the query below I get no results. What am I doing wrong?

```
Cursor cursor = _db.query(_objectName, _fields.keySet().toArray(new String[0]), "parentId=? AND published=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(menuItem), String.valueOf(1)}, null, null, "level");
```

Comment: The query works fine without the published clause. I will have a look t the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your query. The problem must be elsewhere. Check your code and table structure. Maybe you are not sending the right values for `parentId` and `published` columns or the data in the table is not in the format you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use raw query

```
"Select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where published = '"+String.valueOf(1)+"'";
```

You can put your integer value insted of 1